# How do I buy extra email quota for Google Apps for Domain accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I manage a Google Apps domain with about ten users on it.  Only one of the users is a really heavy email user and is about to fill up her email quota.  I would like to find a way to add extra quota to that user.  The only information I can find from the Google help is that I must upgrade all the users to the business edition.  Is there any way that I can just buy some more quota for a single user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that and you will have to upgrade to the Google Apps for Business in order to get more space.

From the [FAQ](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/faq.html) for Google Apps:

> **Can I have a subset of employees on Google Apps for Business and others on Google Apps?**
>
> Google Apps does not support Google Apps and Google Apps for Business user accounts as part of the same organization's Google Apps account.